# How to model a pseudo periodic signal?

Tags: normal-distribution, almost-periodic-functions, quasiperiodic-function

I have a signal $s$ that can take 2 values: $\{0, 1\}$ and is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$:

$s(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$

$s$ is a train of rectangular pulses:

```
 ________        _______
|        |______|       |__
--------------------------------> n
<---A--->
<-------T------>
```

The average of the `1` length among all the cycles of all the signals is $\mu_A$ which I have (let's say `100`) and $\sigma_A$ its scale (ex: `5`).
The average length of 1 cycle among all the cycles of all the signals is $\mu_T$ which I have (let's say `500`) and $\sigma_T$ its scale (ex: `20`).

---

For a given signal $i$ ($s_i$), it also has a specific set of ${\mu_A}_i$ ${\sigma_A}_i$ and ${\mu_T}_i$ ${\sigma_T}_i$ and:

$ {\mu_A}_i \sim  N (\mu_A,\,{\sigma_A}^{2})$

$ {\mu_T}_i \sim  N (\mu_T,\,{\sigma_T}^{2})$

---

For a given cycle $j$ of the signal $s_i$ the length $A$ and $T$ are not constant over time:

$ A_{i,j} \sim  N ({\mu_A}_i,\,{{\sigma_A}_i}^{2})$

$ T_{i,j} \sim  N ({\mu_T}_i,\,{{\sigma_T}_i}^{2})$

---

I was wondering if I have a set of points (`{n=1, y=0}`, `{n=10, y=0}`, `{n=15, y=1}`...), how can I create a model to predict $s_i$ for a given $n$ (ex: $s_i(n = 20)= ?$)?

I'm trying to create a script which give the probability of the the signal being `0` or `1` for a given $n$ from the already known points.